# Let H2 prefix columns

Tags: sql, h2

Maybe that's only possible with `SQLITE` but is there also a trick to let `H2` prefix all the returned `columns` with `table name` of a given `select * query`?

I need to know which table provides which column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix the "SELECT *" statement with "EXPLAIN SELECT *" which gives only the execution plan but nevertheless all returned columns in a real query.

Answer (score 0):

When using JDBC, use [ResultSetMetaData.getTableName](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName_int) to get the table name. You can also get the column name, and the column label (the column label is the same as the column name, except if you use an alias).